# Get bigcommerce orders in reverse date order

Tags: bigcommerce

Using the PHP Bigcommerce library, I want to get a list of all my orders with the newest order on top. This is what I'm using to get my orders:

```
$filter = ['status_id' => 11];
$orders = Bigcommerce::getOrders($filter);
```

It's listing all the orders from oldest to newest. On the API documentation, it says that there is an order filter called 'date_created':

> "If your application relies on the arrival of new orders you may need to check both date_created and status fields (or status_id)."

I've tried passing dates through the filter like so:

```
$filter = ['date_created' => '01/04/2013', 'status_id' => 11];
```

And other formats, like 01-04-13, etc. But none of them return any orders for me.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it seems to be a bug in the way it is documented. You need to use the min_date_created field for filtering instead of date_created. The date should be RFC format "Tue, 20 Nov 2012 00:00:00 +0000"

For instance -

```
$filter = array('min_date_created' => 'Tue, 20 Nov 2012 00:00:00 +0000');
$orders = Bigcommerce::getOrders($filter);
print_r($orders);
```

This will work. Cheers!

Comment: This works for getting orders from a certain date, but I'd like to sort the orders in reverse order from newest to oldest. I'm guessing I should use a sort function on the Order ID field, but I'd like to retrieve the orders in reverse order if possible to reduce load times.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `sort` attribute?

`$filter = ['sort' => 'date_created:desc'];`

Source: Pagination session of [List Orders documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#list-orders).

Answer (score -1):

```
$orders = Bigcommerce::getOrders(array('sort' => 'date_created:desc'));

print_r($orders);
```

This Will Work To show order in descending way.